# Show data based on dropdown selection does not work

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have categories table and clubs table, relationship between is

- A category has many clubs
- 1 category can have many clubs
- 1 club have 1 category

I want to show clubs based on category, which will be selected with dropdown list, so other clubs will be hided. See the Screenshot for more understanding [image]

1. My Controller (I have no issues getting category names to dropdown list):

```php
    public function club()
    {
        $categories_name = Category::pluck('category_name','id'); 
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        $data = array(
            'user_clubs' => $user->clubs,
            'categories_name' => $categories_name
        );
        return view('pages.dashboard.club_dashboard')->with($data);
    }
```

2. My View

```html
<div class="form-group">
        <strong>{{Form::label('categories_name', 'Select Category')}}</strong>
        {{Form::select('categories_name', $categories_name, null, ['class' => 'form-control'], array('name'=>'categories_name[]'))}}
</div>

@if (count($user_clubs)>0)
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>

        <th><strong>Club Name</strong></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($user_clubs as $club)
    <tr id="{{$club->category->id}}">
        <th>{{$club->club_name}} | {{$club->category->category_name}} </th>
        <td><a href="/clubs-soc/lists/{{$club->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
        <td>
            {!!Form::open(['action' => ['ClubsController@destroy', $club->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'float-right'])!!} 
            {{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}} 
                {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}} 
            {!!Form::close()!!}
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
@else
<p>You Have No posts</p>
@endif
```

3.Category Model

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function clubs(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Club');
    }
}
```

4.Club Model

```php
class Club extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

5.My Script
I wrote this script from answer given by friend it still not working please, help me find:

- Where did I make mistake?
- Where should I put the script?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#categories_name").on("change", function(){
            var category_id = $(this).val();
            $("table tr").each(function(index){
                if (index != 0) {
                    $row = $(this);
                    if ($row.attr('id')!=category_id) {
                        $row.hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $row.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });​
</script>
```

Comment: Your table rows don't have an id attribute, but rather than id you should use either data-* attributes or css classes. Element ids should be unique.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I have updated please check, still not working